# how do I find the pci.id for my Netgear WG311v3 wireless network adapter?

Tags: wireless

I have an older Netgear WG311v3 wireless network pci card and I want to find out what PCI.ID for this is to enable it if possible. I know the PCI.ID for Broadcom is 14e4, but am not sure where to find this pci.id for my netgear hardware.

Answer (score 1):

`lspci -vnn | grep -a4 -i net`

This will list all network adapters in your system with their PCI ID.

It will output lines resembling this:

`00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V [8086:15a1] (rev 05)`

That bit in the brackets `[8086:15a1]` is the PCI ID.

http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/mint-linux/176871-solved-cant-find-pci-id.html